# Maximum frequency FPGA

Tags: fpga, frequency

I need to design a component and choose on which FPGA i will implement it.

One module of the FPGA will be synchronous of a signal TXCLK that is generated by an external component the LM98640 and the frequency of TXCLK is about 640 MHz.

I've read the datasheets but i'm not sure which parameter i should check to be sure that the FPGA can work with signals as fast a 640 Mhz

I'm aware that the way i design it will affect the maximum operating frequency, but i'm looking for the values for each FPGA in case the design is really simple of maximum frequency.

I'm confused between Digital Frequency Synthesizer (DFS) or Delay-Locked Loop (DLL) or GTP transceiver clock ?

Thank you

Comment: Seems like you need to run before you learned to walk

Comment: Yes in fact! It is the first time that i have to make a design that including a high speed deserializer

Comment: that means learn to crawl, and walk first before you fail dismally at running

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, yes, I feel a staggering gap here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xilinx's, for example, have very fast giga-bit transceivers that can operate at multi-gigabit/sec rates, but they also have simple serial and parallel shift registers out at the IO edges of their dies that are typically used for the serial to parallel shifting in both directions.  In addition, to get the fastest speeds with synchronous external clocks, I typically use half-rate clocks and DDR (double datarate serializer or de-serializer settings).  Its pretty straightfoward in a series-7 Xilinx to get 1Gb/sec on each LVDS I/O pin when applying a 500Mhz external clock.  This is all done without using the gigabit transceivers.  This also involves no PLLs so it can operate smoothly from low speeds to high speeds continuously.

If you have 640MHz clock today, you may be after 640Mbps on your data lines.  My recommendation would be to use a 320Mhz clock and a 1:4 or 4:1 internal serial-to-parallel or parallel-to-serial converter in DDR mode (See Xilinx OSERDESE2 and ISERDESE2 built-in components).  This would leave your parallel clocking rates in your main logic down at 160Mhz which is OK.

There are good application notes on setting this up.  You can also use the built-in IP features of their development tools to create this component for you.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, everybody advises me to use ISERDESE2 so that is what i'm going to do. The ADC from which i have the data is configurable and the rate is from 40Mbps to 640Mbps, do the ISERDESE2 work at slower rates or do i have to have two different configuration for my design: one using the ISERDESE2 components and the other one using shift registers and flip flops?

Comment: A single configuration will work.  You won't have to use shift registers and flip flops (that's what is inside the ISERDES2 blocks).  These run at any clocking rate so you can change rates easily.

Answer (score 2):

First rule of making a successful project is to start with reference designs usually offered by manufacturer. Using the reference design eliminates a lot of guesses and unnecessary research and development.

The LM98640 is a two-channel 14-bit 40Msps ADC with analog front end, made by formerly "National Semiconductor" (now a part of Texas Instruments), primarily to process CCD sensor data.

[image]

It has a fairly non-standard interface,

> "a unique serial LVDS output format"

with four-lane LVDS (or two-lane DDR), so the 14-bit result is serialized into bursts of seven (or 14) nibbles, followed by a gap in clock, at 320 Mhz clock rate, all wrapped into a "40-Mhz frames".

[image]

Note, the application diagram shows "Image Processor/ASIC", not "FPGA". So, I have serious doubts that the standard SERDES offered in modern Xilinx FPGAs can be configured to handle this odd interface.

However, further look into corresponding TI page reveals that there are (a) [Evaluation board](http://www.ti.com/tool/lm98640cval), and (b) development kit to evaluate the ADC, called "[Wavevision 5 Data Capture Board](http://www.ti.com/tool/WAVEVSN-BRD-5.1)"

Inspection of free downloadable SDK reveals that the Wavevision board is based on Xilinx Virtex-4 FPGA, XC4VLX25-11FFG668 in particular. It is quite apparent that designers did make quite an effort in place and route to accommodate the LM98640 interface at straight 320 MHz.

Unfortunately, Virtex-4 chips are 3-4 generations old, and are quite difficult to source. It should be possible to re-compile the RTL (not offered in SDK) into Virtex-6/7 platforms, but differences in underlying building blocks (slices architecture) would require fresh (and challenging) effort to close the design timing.

Giving the level of OP question (DFS/DLL/GTP), I would strongly advise to get both boards (it will cost about $5,000, plus Vivado/ISE license), and, if this is meant as a product, COPY EXACTLY what they do and how it is done.

Answer (score 1):

Your are looking on the wrong direction.

The device you mention has an LVDS I/F. Typical LVDS and Serdes I/F have a first stage working at serial high speed, but then the data is converted from serial to parallel greatly reducing the speed needed on the FPGA to process the data.

I would advice to have a talk with a local FAE from any of the major FPGA suppliers on your area.

Comment: But the goal actually was not to use the Serdes, i wanted to deserialize the data using the signal TXCLK with a shift register

Comment: Forget about that! Only special I/O blocks can work at 640MHz. Luckily you don't need an FAE for that, just look at the highest speed of the I/O ports. Probably the LVDS type.

Comment: And if i have my TXCLK at 320 MHz and that i shift the register on each event of the TXCLK (rising and falling edge) will i still need a serdes?

Comment: @thedude Yes, because the pin DFFs would have to change the pin state at 640 MHz. But that's why serdes were put into newer FPGAs anyway. Are you trying to use a super-cheap FPGA or something? FPGAs with serdes on every I/O are relatively low-cost and plentiful.

Comment: No actually i can use a relatively new FPGA, i just wanted to avoid using serdes. I have been reading various guideline about using them but all seemed really unclear i don't understand how to combine them to be able to parralelize the bitstream in 14 bits words. I had also another issue is that the transition of my TXCLK are aligned on the center of the data eye of the bitstream and what i understood about serdes is that it works with clk and data aligned on the transition edges.